# UI is being "pushed" down on smaller screens and there's a lot of white (blank) space at the bottom and at the top

Tags: flutter

Please check the screenshots bellow in order to help understand what the issue is.

**Screenshots:**

[Emulator vs Real Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHEt6.jpg)

*Basically the Emulator version is exactly how I'd expect the app to look like on all mobile devices, that's the desired outcome, but on the real device you can see it's not the desired outcome, far from it.*

[With the mobile language button visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jnEI.png)

*A lot of empty space around the mobile language button.*

[With the mobile language button not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9pAb.jpg)

*Empty space/rectangle coming from somewhere, not really sure where it's coming from but it seems to stay even after the mobile language button appears (after the window gets resized down to mobile breakpoint)*

The issue seems to happen on smaller screens, and what bothers me is that there are only a few widgets on the login page; It should have no issue fitting them all on a screen, even if the resolution is smaller. There also seems to be some additional white space at the bottom of the page and  In the screenshots I have attached.

On smaller screens the whole UI is pushed down by something which I do not know what it is, given that I do not have that many widgets on screen at the moment I don't really understand why it's behaving like that, you can see a big spacing gap at the top of the screen, between the logo and the top margin/edge of the window/screen which is there by default but can be scrolled over when the content is scrolled up, however I do not understand why the content is scrolled down by default to being with.

The issue seems to only happen on smaller screens at the moment but I am expecting it to happen on bigger screens as well as soon as a page has enough UI content to fill the entire screen, which tells me that something in the way I've structured my UI must be wrong.

*I am still new to Flutter and I may not have a deep understanding of what widgets should I choose for my specific scenario, if you do see something wrong in regards with the way I've structured my layout or with my code please let me know, if it can be done better I have no issue in refactoring it, as long as I know what I need to refactor exactly and how.
The reason I want to fix this before moving further is because I want to learn how to properly structure my UI to be adaptive/reactive on as many platforms/screen sizes as possible, if I start out with a good UI ethic it should make it easier for me down the line, when pages become much more complex.
Also if you need more details, please let me know and I'll do my best to clarify things, if needed. Thank you very much.*

**I'm also providing the full code for my login page down bellow.**

```dart
solved
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I tried to troubleshoot my UI and so far I can't find the root cause of the issues I am having, so far the only presumption I have is that this could because by the first issue described bellow, and although I tried moving that element in and out of the scroll list I can't retain its full functionality after moving it (read bellow).

What I've tried so far:

1. Moving the `mobileLanguageSelector` inside the `SingleChildScrollView` while still keeping its  `if (constraints.maxWidth <= mobileBreakpoint) { do this }` functionality working.

The mobileLanguageSelector button is outside the scrolling area, which makes it fixed, which in return affects the UI on smaller screens. I have tried to move it inside the scrolling widget but then it no longer disappears when the window size is bigger.

2. If i wrap the `Column` widget inside the `SingleChildScrollView` with a `LayoutBuilder` something breaks in my login function and the screen is stuck on a never ending loading loop after the log-in button is being pressed.